# Problem doing math with point values in highcharts tooltip.pointFormat

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a graph with highcharts. I'm trying to have a custom string be displayed when hovering over the points in the scatter graph. This string requires that I manipulate the data from that point a little bit, but I am not able to do that.

I know that one can access the data doing the following 
'{point.y}'
but that doesn't allow me to manipulate the data (divide, Math.floor, ... it). I'm assuming that in order to do this I need to concatenate the portion where I manipulate the data with '+'. However nothing I've tried grabs the data like `{point.y}` does. 
I've tried 'this.y', 'this.point.y'
I'm not really sure what works

```
...
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.y} ' + this.y
},
...
```

I am supposed to obtain what I would obtain with `{point.y}` with `this.y` so I can manipulate the data. So

```
Expected: 14.345354 14.345354
Actual: 14.345354 undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pointFormatter` instead to specify a function that returns the desired value. With `pointFormat` you can only supply a string, with variables enclosed in curly brackets.

Using the `pointFormatter` ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter)) you can program the result specifically.  For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dom98Leb/)):

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        return 'x: <b>'+this.x+'</b><br/>y: <b>'+this.y+'</b><br/>'
    }
}
```

Would be similar to the default point format. Or to floor the X- and Y-value:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormatter: function() {
        return 'x: <b>'+Math.floor(this.x)+'</b><br/>y: <b>'+Math.floor(this.y)+'</b><br/>'
    }
}
```